# Is “for+object” a part of a non-finite clause?

Tags: to-infinitive, for

For example, is “for me” in “it’s necessary for me to learn English” a part of a non-finite clause or just a independent prepositional phrase?

Comment: @Man_from_India's answer is right. Note that "me" is not object of "for" but subject of the infinitival clause "for me to learn English".

Comment: @BillJ can you help me identify the subject? "with that comes different strategies". But I think "with that" is the subject. Notice the third person singular form of verb - *comes*. Make it a question: "does with that come different strategies?" Attach a tag question: "with that comes different strategies, doesn't that?" What's the subject. I don't think the tag question is not correct. Please help.

Comment: I remember what H&P says about preposition phrase as subject. In my sentence the preposition phrase is not like the one H&P talks about. But still due to the form of *come* and inversion test I tend to believe the PP is the subject. But if we add a tag question, I think "different strategies" should be the subject. So I am confused here.

Comment: @Man_From_India I'd say it's a case of subject-dependent inversion. The basic non-inverted version with tag would be "Different strategies come with that, don't they?", where the pro-form "that" refers to something mentioned in the preceding discourse.

Comment: @BillJ I understand. But two things stopping me. Look at the form of verb "come". Third person singular. And "different strategies" is plural, and need "come". Further the interrogative sentence can be framed like this as well: "does with that come different strategies?" Or is my interrogative sentence wrong?

Comment: @Man_From_India Your interrogative sentence is ungrammatical. The verb in your original example should be "come", not "comes", i.e "with that come different strategies".

Comment: @BillJ in that case I have no problem with your explanation. Btw I found that sentence on COCA

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"for me" in your example sentence is part of the non finite infinitive clause. "for" here is a sub-ordinator that introduces the subject of the infinitive clause. That "to" is also not a preposition but a subordinator.